# Embedding a SoundCloud recording right away?

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

Basically I want the user to record a sound with the SoundCloud recorder and once they click save, the sound they just recorded will be embedded on to my webpage.

I use the SC.record() method to get the recording. This is my function for where I save the recordings... Right now nothing is embedded when I try to run it

```
$('#save a').click(function(e) {
  var currentURL ="";
  e.preventDefault();
  SC.connect({
    connected: function() {
      $('.status').html('Uploading...');
      SC.recordUpload({
        track: {
          title: 'whatever',
          sharing: 'public'
        }
      }, function(track) {
        currentURL = '"'+track.permalink_url+'"';
        $('#SCtracks').append('<li id='+currentURL+'>'+currentURL+'</li>');
          SC.oEmbed(currentURL, {color: "ff0066"},  document.getElementById(currentURL));
      });
    }
  });
 });
```

But if I go in and call SC.oEmbed with a URL to a recording I made earlier it works fine.

So I think I might be trying to embed the recording before it is fully uploaded, but I don't know where else I could put that statement. 
Thanks

Comment: With this question, you're on a good way to get the `Tumbleweed` badge :P

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/soundcloudapi/Tee5ENOAW2s/7zoETMziI6IJ) answered my question. I guess you have to just keep checking the state until it is for sure done. If someone know a quicker way please answer